# Set delegate in static method swift

Tags: ios, swift, delegates, static-methods

In my app I've an driver to connect it to a scale. My app should use scale in a few parts of code, so I made an helper to simplify code.
My helper has this code:

```
    protocol ScalesHelperDelegate {
        func scalesHelperDelegate_error()
        func scalesHelperDelegate_pluSavedWithSuccess()
    }

    public class ScalesHelper {
        static var delegate: ScalesHelperDelegate?
        public static func getBill(scaleIp:String, scalePort:Int, barcode:String) {
            let scalesManager = ScalesManager.init()
            scalesManager.delegate = self as? ScalesManagerDelegate
            let scaleConfig = ScalesConfig.init(ip: scaleIp, port: scalePort)
            scalesManager.getBillFromScale(config: scaleConfig, scaleType: .type, bill: barcode, time: 3.0)
        }
    }

    extension ScalesHelper: ScalesManagerDelegate {
        public func scalesManagerDelegate_error() {
            ScalesHelper.delegate?.scalesHelperDelegate_error()
        }

        public func scalesManagerDelegate_success(rowsFromScale: [WeightedProduct]?) {
            if let weightedPrd = rowsFromScale {
//For now I don't do nothing
            } else {
                ScalesHelper.delegate?.scalesHelperDelegate_pluSavedWithSuccess()
            }
        }
    }
```

when I try to run the app and use this helper I saw that `scalesManager.delegate` is always nil and it never calls the delegate methods (look in extension). There's a way to user a static func with a delegate?
Thank you

Answer (score 2, accepted):

self inside static method refers to the type itself (ScalesHelper in your case)
Maybe you need to convert ScalesHelper into singleton class. Then you will not need a static function.
Here is how to make a singleton class for your reference
https://developer.apple.com/documentation/swift/cocoa_design_patterns/managing_a_shared_resource_using_a_singleton